# How to generate random dates inside csv file using perl script?

Tags: perl, csv

I haven't used Perl scripts before. Below mentioned is my required output in csv file.

```
email_id,          CVupload_date,Login_date,Reg_date
example1@gmail.com,10-10-2010,19-5-2014,1-1-2010
example2@gmail.com,15-1-2011,19-5-2014,10-2-2010
example3@gmail.com,10-11-2012,19-5-2014,13-10-2011
```

Can anyone help me out for generating csv file like this, using Perl script. I need add multiple records in this file. I just given a sample of my file format. With your help I'll try to figure out the working of Perl script.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used Perl ever before? Do you have Perl installed? Do you know how to execute Perl scripts? Do you know how to install things from CPAN?

If the answer to all of the above are "no" - this seems a bit ambitious. If the answer to any/most of the above are "yes" then you might be in some luck.

[Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) is a third party module you might like to use to write to a CSV.

What you would need to do is build up the data you need into, say, an array, and then print that array out to a file using Text::CSV_XS.

The last paragraph of the synopsis shows how to print out data to a CSV.

You can store the data in an array of arrays, so each item in the array represents each row in the CSV and each item of the array in the row array represents each column in the row:

```
[
    [ row1xcol1, row1xcol2, row1xcol3 ],
    [ row2xcol1, row2xcol2, row2xcol3 ],
    ...
]
```

If you do attempt this - and why not, it's a good learning experience - do yourself a favour and add these two pragmas to the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

They help to highlight silly mistakes which are all to easy to make otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
say 'email_id,          CVupload_date,Login_date,Reg_date';
for (1..30) {
    say 'example', $_, '@gmail.com,25-5-2004,22-6-2014,16-11-2003'; # guaranteed random, generated by random.org
}
```

Comment: Reference is of course http://xkcd.com/221/ which I'd normally upvote. But -1 for trolling the OP. I think it is reasonable to assume he/she has a real need, but a poor understanding of what Stack Overflow is about. Which is not a crime.

Comment: Hi @Oesor, i just got what u said. Is there any way to generate the Date Randomly?

Comment: Yes. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html (Found by googling "perl random")